# parse JSON array in excel vba

Tags: arrays, json, excel, http-post, vba

I have done a post URL and I get JSON format respondtext. 
I want to get "barcodes" starting from cell(1,1)
This is what JSON response is:

```
"{
    ""status"": ""success"",
    ""message"": ""5 New Barcode(s) Generated for batch 5924592"",
    ""data"": {
        ""batch"": ""5924592"",
        ""barcodes"": [
            ""MN8HY6"",
            ""5BZZ9K"",
            ""9R6QKR"",
            ""869P8Z"",
            ""XK2UXZ""
        ]
    }
}"
```

Here is what I have written so far on VBA excel

```
Dim Json As Object
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim Parsed As Dictionary 
Dim Item As Dictionary    

'Post
xmlhttp.Open "POST", "url", False
'setting auth headers
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "token"

Dim Bqty As Variant
Dim bID As Variant

Bqty = Sheets("sheet1").Range("f1").Value
bID = Sheets("sheet1").Range("f4").Value

xmlhttp.send "action=" & "createBarcodes" & _
Chr(38) & "barcodes=" & Bqty & _
Chr(38) & "batch=" & bID


JsonString = xmlhttp.responseText

Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.responseText)
Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.responseText)

 Dim i As Integer
 i = 1
 For Each Item In Parsed("data")
 Sheets("Batch ID").Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("barcodes")
 i = i + 1
 Next
```

Please if someone can help as I have spent all day figuring this out. I am not a professional VBA developer.

Thank you

Comment: i get an error, "OBJECT REQUIRED" when i run my script :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a JSON library?

```
Dim i As Long, strresp As String, bcodes As Variant

strresp = xmlhttp.responseText

strresp = Mid(strresp, InStr(1, strresp, Chr(91) & Chr(32) & Chr(34) & Chr(34)) + 4)
strresp = Left(strresp, InStrRev(strresp, Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(32) & Chr(93)) - 1)

bcodes = Split(strresp, Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & Chr(32) & Chr(34) & Chr(34))

For i = LBound(bcodes) To UBound(bcodes)
    Debug.Print bcodes(i)
Next i

Worksheets("Batch ID").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(bcodes) + 1, 1) = _
    Application.Transpose(bcodes)
```

Granted all the Chr()'s make it look messy but I hate doubling up quotes within a quoted string.

Comment: I agree on the double quotes. My preference would to use a const in that scenario: `Const dq = Chr(34) & Chr(34)`. Probably not the best programming tactic, but I am not known for the best practices sometimes

Comment: This was just a demo and its usefulness is going to depend on what the responseText *actually* looks like. Probably better to Mid the string between `[` and `]` then regex out the barcodes from there.